# RESTful service response isn't mapping to an object - RESTKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, restkit

I have a JSON response from REST service I am using RESTKit and its not getting mapped , below is the source for the same

```
RKObjectMapping *userMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [userMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"strCode" toKeyPath:@"UserCode"]];



    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping
                                                                                   objectClass:[User class]
                                                                                   rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST];

    RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class]];

    [responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"Id":@"Id",@"UserCode":@"strCode",@"FirstName": @"strFname", @"LastName": @"strLname",@"Email":@"strEmail",@"PhoneNumber":@"strPhoneNumber",@"CompanyName":@"strCompany",@"Address":@"strAddress",@"Abn":@"strAbn"}];

    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:nil
                                                                                           keyPath:nil
                                                                                       statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];

    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    [manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

    [manager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];


    RKObjectMapping *errResponseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ServiceError class]];

    [errResponseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"ErrorMessage": @"strErrorMessage", @"FriendlyMessage": @"strFriendlyMessage"}];


    RKResponseDescriptor *errResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errResponseMapping
                                                                                               method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                          pathPattern:nil
                                                                                              keyPath:nil
                                                                                          statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];



    [manager addResponseDescriptor:errResponseDescriptor];

    manager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

    User *user = [user new];
    user.strCode = txtCode.text;


    // POST the parameterized representation of the `page` object to `/posts` and map the response
    [manager postObject:user path:[ServiceUrls userDetails] parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
           NSlog(@"%d",result.count);
        }

    } failure:nil];
```

The user class looks like this

```
@interface User : NSObject
{

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSNumber *Id;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *strCode;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *strFname;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *strLname;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *strEmail;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *strPhoneNum;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *strCompany;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *strAddress;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *strAbn;


@end
```

JSON response that i get but isn't mapping is as follows

```
    {"Id":7,
"UserCode":"CC1234",
"FirstName":"Test name_",
"LastName":"Banga",
"Email":"p@b.com",
"PhoneNumber":"0421196587",
"CompanyName":"String",
"Address":"String",
"Abn":"String"}
```

Not sure whats wrong with the code I have added, any clue ?

Comment: Do you get any error? is object empty? have you tried to exclude fields in order to get at least one working?

Comment: @NickCatib there is no error , just says didn't find any mappable object, i didn't tried removing any fields as such

Comment: @NickCatib even with just one field it does work still get empty result object

Comment: Can you try with user as a parent for the JSON? I refer to example on https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping

Comment: There is no keyPath to the JSON so can't use user as parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this.
Mapping:

```
-(void) getUserMapping {  
    RKEntityMapping *userEntityMapping = [self generateEntityMappingFromClass:[User class]];
    userEntityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"Id"];
    return userEntityMapping;
}
```

Generate Mapping:

```
+ (RKEntityMapping *)generateEntityMappingFromClass:(Class)objectClass {
    NSAssert(objectClass != NULL, @"Cannot generate a mapping from a null object class.");
    NSDictionary *propertiesAndClasses = [[RKPropertyInspector sharedInspector] propertyInspectionForClass:objectClass];
    NSAssert([propertiesAndClasses count] > 0, @"Cannot generate a mapping from a class containing zero properties.");
    RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass(objectClass) inManagedObjectStore: [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
    NSMutableDictionary *mappingDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (NSString *property in [propertiesAndClasses allKeys]) {
        NSLog(@"property: %@", property);
        [mappingDictionary setObject:property forKey:property];
    }

[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:mappingDictionary];
return mapping;
}
```

Response descriptor:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptorBody = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[self getUserMapping] method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"" keyPath:@"" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

I think your problem is JSON without keyPath, try to change it from nil to @""